# npm module development dependencies

Tags: node.js, development-environment, npm-install

I am developing a node.js module in combination with a bigger master node.js project using that module.

During development that module is located in a folder outside the master project. Thus, during development, it should not be installed via npm install.

For production deployment the module's repository must of course be part of the dependencies. But, as I wrote – it should not be installed during development.

It's like this:

```
/home/dev/
          master
          module
```

package.json

```
{
    "name":"master"
    "dependencies": {
        "mymodule": "somewhere on git server" // ** only for production
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can fetch modules from github as well as your local machine location.

```
{
   "name": "master",
   "dependencies": {
       "git_module": "github_username/repo", // eg. LongHike/testApp (where LongHike is github account and testApp is repo)
       "local_module": "file:../your_module" // local machine location (.. represents cd command)
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Well, I don't want to fetch the module on the local machine, since it's already there. I only want to fetch it for production.

Comment: Then `"git_module": "github_username/repo"` will help you

Comment: And how do you manage that the module is only loaded from git in production?

See, my qustion is not how to load a module from git, but how to prevent that it's being loaded from git during development.

Comment: I think you cannot define that module is only loaded from git when application in in prod. You have to stick either git or local according to your application env.

Comment: But if I stick with git and I do an npm intall on my local machine, I have two colliding versions of my module.

And if I do local only, then my package.json lacks the module entry.

Comment: `"local_module": "file:../your_module"`

This not even necessary if one simply places the module in a nodes_module directory in an ancestor directory.